# Javascript Passing variable not working in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem passing a variable to my ajax where:

This will work: url: 'testing.php?id=1',

and this will not work: url: 'testing.php?id=theid',

Here is the full code which works:

```
function myfunc(theid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testing.php?user_id=1',
        success: function() {
            alert('this worked' + venueid);
        }
    });
}
```

And this code does not pass the variable value:

```
function myfunc(theid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testing.php?user_id=theid',
        success: function() {
            alert('this worked' + venueid);
        }
    });
}
```

Is this a syntax issue? What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: url : 'testing.php?user_id=' + theid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myfunc(theid) {
$.ajax({
   url: 'testing.php?user_id='+ theid,
   success: function(){
   alert('this worked' + venueid);
                    }
});
}
```

Comment: Be sure to declare theid too :)